# DELTE HTTP method is not working with Spring data rest module

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a boot app

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I have a repository, I dont have a controller to take an advantage of Spring Data Rest Moduel. Am using SPRING DATA REST to expose HTTP methods

```
public interface PUCCRepository extends CrudRepository<PUCCertificate, Long> {

    @Transactional
    Long deleteByVehicleNo(@RequestParam("vehicleNo") String vehicleNo);
   
}
```

Now am trying to do a Delete request from UI(Angular). Its deleting the record when am doing a **GET** request for deleteByVechicleNo but it not deleting a record when i do **DELETE** request.

I attached the success and failure scenarios for your reference.

Get Request
[image]

Delete Request
[image]

Comment: You have to explicitly mention @DeleteMapping for a delete request, because default mapping is Get.

Comment: Where i have to mention @DeleteMapping? I mentioned that I dont have controller. I want to achieve this without controller.

Comment: Try using @DeleteMapping("/url_endpoint") on the repository method

Answer (score 0):

This is because any extra methods you define on your repository are considered search operations by default (meant for read-only).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.search-resource

To add custom behaviour you have to implements an MVC controller annotated with @RepositoryRestController where you can define any extra operation you like.

You can read more about this approach in here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers

You may also want to annotate your repository method with *@RestResource(exported = false)* so it does not get picked up as a search operation.